# What are more effective alternatives to Biafine and Epitheliale AH?

Tags: dermatology, sun-burn, vitiligo

My friend has an extreme form of vitiligo so she has developed an extreme sensitivity to sun light and gets sunburns quickly. She uses Biafine often and also Epitheliale AH.

What are more effective alternatives to Biafine and Epitheliale AH?

Comment: Solution for what? Are you asking for alternate treatments for vitiligo (if so, she really should look into UV therapy, it worked wonders for my sister) for alternate ways of protecting herself from the sun or for alternate moisturizing creams? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Done @terdon. TIA.

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. It would be even better if you could explain precisely why the products she uses aren't good enough. As it stands, you are basically asking for a list of alternatives. Could you narrow it down and specify precisely what she would need that her current creams don't offer? On a side note, if she hasn't looked into UV therapy, she really should ask her doctor about it. I couldn't believe the difference it made for my sister who also has a pretty serious case of Vitiligo. Not 80%, perhaps, but certainly ~50%. UV is the only thing we've seen that was able to reduce it.